# How to Copy Listview.SelectedItems to clipboard in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I want to used ContextMenuStrip Right click to Get Listview.selectedItem 's text and Copy to clipboard

Comment: Private Sub Copy_ToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Copy_ToolStripMenuItem.Click
        Dim A As String = ListView1.FocusedItem.Text
        Clipboard.SetText(A)
    End Sub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first add your ContextmenuStrip to your Listview

```
Dim cm As ContextMenuStrip = cms_Listview    
ListView1.ContextMenuStrip = cm
```

Then just copy the selected listview item in the ToolStripMenuItem.click event to clipboard

```
Private Sub tsmi_copy_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles tsmi_copy.Click
    If ListView1.SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub
    Clipboard.Clear()
    Clipboard.SetText(ListView1.SelectedItems(0).Text)
End Sub
```